Fastlane match did not create provisioning profile
I ran fastlane match appstore and it did create a certificate and stored it in github. But it did not create the provisioning profile. Upon uploading the provisioning profile manually fastlane asked for match passphrase and upon entering the correct one it failed.
enter image description here
enter image description here
How to manage certificate and provisioning profile such that it gets recognized by fastlane.
I have tried deleting the provisiong profile from github.
